# Using breakpoints with remote debugger

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, breakpoints, pdb-files

Suppose you open an asp.net solution in vs2010 and set breakpoints. And then you deploy the asp.net application remotely in IIS 7 on a box that has msvsmon running.

1) Do the breakpoints get saved in the pdb files?

2) Will the remote debugger msvsmon break on those breakpoints if you attach visual studio 2010 to the worker process running the asp.net application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:

PDB files do not contain breakpoints info, they just have program information that enable debugging (matching statements with source code lines, etc ...)

Second:

Yes, that's the point of the remote debugger, so you can debug a remote process using your local visual studio.

Comment: What files do you need to copy over to the remote machine to copy over the breakpoints or is it even possible?

Comment: just deploy fresh dlls and pdbs. set your breakpoints in your latest code and attach to the remote process. start you application, once the process reaches your "local" breakpoint it'll break and you can debug.
make sure to run the remote debugger as Administrator

Comment: I copied the dlls and pdbs and still get no source available

Comment: Weird, make sure you're building your projects in debug mode. and if its a web app to turn on debugging in web.config.

Comment: Here is a good article on how to use remote debugger
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx

Comment: Yeah for now I am giving up on remote debugging. I tried for a day and a half